# WebStorm Terminal Encoding / Font problem

Tags: encoding, webstorm, powerline

I have problem with the Encoding of WebStorm (and other IntelliJ derivatives). I Installed it a view Minutes ago so no custom configuration is involved. I am on a Mac.

When I start a Terminal inside WebStorm I get the following prompt:

```
_p9k_get_icon:14: character not in range                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Raphaels-MBP%
```

The powerline is not working, the path is missing, and the _p9k.... stuff keeps popping up on every line.

On iTerm and vscode it looks like this

[image]

I use the same font as inside iTerm and vsCcode. If I check the locale everything has a different setting:

vscode:

```
~/Source ❯ locale
LANG="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

iTerm:

```
~ ❯ locale
LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=
```

WebStorm and other IntelliJ:

```
locale
LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=
```

If I set the locale to en_GB.UTF-8 and start another zsh, the error (character not in range) is gone, but the powerline is still not working.

after `export LC_ALL="en_GB.UTF-8"`

```
Raphaels-MBP% locale
LANG="en_DE.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_GB.UTF-8"
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Going to Preferences -> Tools -> Terminal and setting the following environment variable: `LC_CTYPE=UTF-8` fixed it for me, but it just works for the current project.

For a more permanent solution, you can add `export LC_CTYPE=UTF-8` to the top of your `~/.zshrc`.